# NormalQueryReactor Issue

Tags: c#, class, interface

> Error 1   'Plus.Database.Adapter.NormalQueryReactor' does not implement interface member 'Plus.Database.Interfaces.IQueryAdapter.GetTable()'  C:\Users\xintel\Desktop\Boon Emu\Database\Adapter\NormalQueryReactor.cs 7   18  Plus Emulator

NormalQueryReactor.cs

```
using System;

using Plus.Database.Interfaces;

namespace Plus.Database.Adapter
{
    public class NormalQueryReactor : QueryAdapter, IQueryAdapter, IRegularQueryAdapter, IDisposable
    {
        public NormalQueryReactor(IDatabaseClient Client)
            : base(Client)
        {
            base.command = Client.createNewCommand();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            base.command.Dispose();
            base.client.reportDone();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to fix.

Comment: I think your error message tells you _exactly_ why it's happening.

Comment: @CodingGorilla You've also been programming for 30 years. I somehow doubt OP has that much experience...

Comment: @TylerH It doesn't take a lot of experience to understand a message which says: `does not implement interface member`, that seems pretty clear to me

Comment: @CodingGorilla So then it stands to reason that however much experience is needed to understand it is at least a little more than xIntel has, hence his question. If he understood the error message, he wouldn't have asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is very explicit. To recap: `IQueryAdapter` declares method `GetTable()` that you have not implemented in your `NormalQueryReactor` class. You need to provide method implementations for all methods declared in interfaces from which you inherit. You missed this one.